# Sendgrid Email Template Dark Mode

Tags: email, sendgrid, email-templates, darkmode

Is there any way to update color scheme for email templates on dark mode? My primary targets are Gmail, Outlook on Android / IOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email Rendering in Dark Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005007/email-rendering-in-dark-mode)